# file_get_contents 403 Forbidden in some links

Tags: php, wordpress, file-get-contents, cloudflare

I am trying to do this

```
$str = '{ "Json": ' . file_get_contents("http://studiofutbol.com.ec/?feed=json") . '}';
```

but I keep getting the error: failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden, and when I tried to use curl to get the content I got the message that I have been banned. What is weird is that I can do:

```
$str = '{ "Json": ' . file_get_contents("http://studiofutbol.com.ec/") . '}';
```

With no issues and I get all the content. I wonder what could be happening with "http://studiofutbol.com.ec/?feed=json" this link.

I also tried $str = '{ "Json": ' . file_get_contents("http://studiofutbol.com.ec/?feed=json") . '}'; from another totally different server and it worked, so what could be happening?

BTW I am the server admin. I use cloudflare, and it is a wordpress site as you may see.

PD: I just installed wprocket and I noticed this just after that.

EDIT: Now I am using $str = '{ "Json": ' . file_get_contents("http://127.0.0.1/?feed=json") . '}'; and it is working, but I still wonder what is going on with the banned stuff

Comment: Can you post the full contents, including headers for the `403 response`? What web server are you using? (Apache/Nginx?)

Comment: @CameronHurd how can I get the header for that error? and I am using Apache

Comment: I think your server IP is already blocked by studiofutbol.com.ec or your cloudflare blocked to get outside source. I think better contact your support or checking your firewall configuration.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, some hosting providers restricts the `file_get_contents()` function. Instead, you should use

```
wp_remote_get("http://studiofutbol.com.ec/")
```

Comment: This is totally unrelated to the question... if your host disabled that function (or fopen stream wrapper, to be precise) you would get a different kind of message. A 403 status code means the connection succeeded but the server (or some service in between) decided something is wrong with the client and returned a 403.